# Python - How to make multiply a given number to a given string

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I want to display a deck and output the number of cards.

Here are the cards:
side note: middle column is the power, last column is the number of cards for that name.

```
Admiral,30,1
General,25,1
Colonel,20,2
Major,15,2
Captain,10,2
Lieutenant,7,2
Sergeant,5,4
Corporal,3,6
Private,1,10
```

The number column represent the number of cards there is for that name. I want it to print out the following below using append. I know I'm suppose to append the rank column to the deck using a for loop, but I'm not sure how to code that.

The output is suppose to be:

```
['Admiral', 'General', 'Colonel', 'Colonel', 'Major', 'Major', 'Captain', 'Captain', 'Lieutenant', 'Lieutenant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private']
There are 30 cards in the deck.
```

my code here:

```
while True: 
    text = rankFile.readline()
    #rstrip removes the newline character read at the end of the line
    text = text.rstrip("\n")     
    if text=="": 
        break
    data = text.split(",")
    rankList.append(data[0])
    powerList.append(int(data[1]))
    numberList.append(int(data[2]))
    
    for i in range(0, len(rankList)): 
        rankList.append(numberList[i])  # this wont work since number is an integer but how can I modifiy this... 

rankFile.close() 

print(50*"=") 
print("\t\tLevel 3 Deck") 
print(50*"=") 
print (rankList) 
print (powerList) 
print (numberList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `list.extend` method to add specific number of cards:

```
cards = []
with open('cards.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        r, p, n = line.strip().split(',')
        cards.extend((r, p) for _ in range(int(n)))

ranks, powers = zip(*cards)

print(ranks)
print(powers)
```

Prints:

```
('Admiral', 'General', 'Colonel', 'Colonel', 'Major', 'Major', 'Captain', 'Captain', 'Lieutenant', 'Lieutenant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private')
('30', '25', '20', '20', '15', '15', '10', '10', '7', '7', '5', '5', '5', '5', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
```